# SMTP email sending failure in Plesk, with following DNS settings

Tags: php, smtp, plesk

I have a Plesk server configuration on which i have added multiple domains. I want to set SMTP to send emails. But it is not working. Don't know what is the problem. I am attaching screan shot of my DNS settings page. Is there any problems here? as on localhost my SMTP is working and sending email, but on plesk it is not sending.[image]

Comment: It appears you are using Google for your email hosting, you need to check your email options in your google account & allow SMTP connections from there. if it's already enabled then you might have a firewall issue.

Comment: Where can i find "email options in my google account" can you guide me?